# Different versions of OpenFace

Tags: python, c++, face-recognition

I've been using the following C++ **OpenFace** project for some time:
https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace

I am thinking to try different Python project which is called **OpenFace** too: 
https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface

I tried to understand how these two projects are related but unsuccessfully.

Please explain whether these two projects are different implementations of the same algorithm(s)? Should I expect identical results from both libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different projects with different goals

[First project](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace) concentrates on facial landmarks, eye gaze direction, head pose and very important Facial Action units calculation which lead to decoding of the facial emotions (smile, sad etc.)

[Second project](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface) dedicated entirely to face recognition task and they are doing it with high degree of accuracy

Answer (score 0):

You might get result difference in performance. Output will be 99% identical as per my experience.